# IndexedDB not saving in Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I have the following method which when called, it adds a record to the database

```
function addObservableStates()
{
    var request = db.transaction(['ObservableStates'],"readwrite").objectStore('ObservableStates').add(observableState);

    request.onerror = function(event)
    {
        console.log("Unable to add observableState to table ObservableStates");
    }
    request.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        console.log("Observable State Added");
    }
}
```

It is not going in any of the onerror or onsuccess callbacks and no console errors are being shown. When I go on the database table, it simply shows no records. However, the database and the required tables are being created. I tried using put() instead of add() (although both should work just the same) but no records were being added.

ObservableState is a variable I created and it contains a value.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the other follow-up questions that have been asked: try adding `oncomplete` and `onabort` handlers to the transaction to observe if it completed successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

- Are you catching exceptions using a try/catch at any point around this function?
- Where is the db variable defined?
- When is the db variable assigned a value?
- Why is this question tagged as jquery?